# Customer Section's images stacked vertically on mobile screens bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am trying to design my company's website. But all images in the customer section are stacked vertically on mobile devices. I am using Bootstrap 5.2. I have tried `col-xs` and `col-md` classes but was not able to achieve the output. I am attaching the code and image. Thanks For the Help.

[image: Current Output]
[image: Desierd Output]

```css
/*
===========================================
    Customer Section
===========================================
*/

.dot {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #3736b0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 105rem;
  left: 50%;
}

.section-4-title {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 108rem;
}

.section-4 {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.card {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 7rem;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


.card-3 {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 8rem;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<!-- 
    ===========================================
       Customer Logo Section
    ===========================================
    -->

    <div class="container">
      <section class="section-4">
        <div class="container text-center">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
              <div class="dot"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <h2 class="section-4-title">
              Simplifying communications for Industry
              <div class="title-highlighter">Leaders in India and World</div>
            </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="container">
            <!-- Customer Row 1 -->
            <div class="row bg-primary">
              <div class="bg-dark col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="card">
                  <img src="svgs/logo-1.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="Logo 1" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="card">
                  <img src="svgs/logo-2.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="Logo 2" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="card card-3">
                  <img src="svgs/logo-3.svg" alt="Logo 3" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="card">
                  <img src="svgs/logo-4.svg" alt="Logo 4" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="card">
                  <img src="svgs/logo-5.svg" alt="Logo 5" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                <div class="card">
                  <img src="svgs/logo-6.svg" alt="Logo 6" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Customer Row 2 -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="card">
                  <img
                    src="svgs/logo-7.svg"
                    class="card-img-top"
                    alt="Logo 7"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="card">
                  <img
                    src="svgs/logo-8.svg"
                    class="card-img-top"
                    alt="Logo 8"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="card card-3">
                  <img
                    src="svgs/logo-9.svg"
                    class="card-img-top"
                    alt="Logo 9"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="card card-10 py-2">
                  <img
                    src="svgs/logo-10.svg"
                    class="card-img-top"
                    alt="Logo 10"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="card card-3">
                  <img
                    src="svgs/logo-11.svg"
                    class="card-img-top"
                    alt="Logo 11"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="card">
                  <img
                    src="svgs/logo-12.svg"
                    class="card-img-top"
                    alt="Logo 12"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: I want the site should look perfect on all devices, including laptops, large desktops, tablets, and mobiles as well.

Comment: I am playing with different values. But not getting the desired output. Please guide me if you know how to achieve the output.